# Reading and writing file in ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, io, file-handling

I have file encoded in ISO-8859-1. I'm trying to read it in as a single String, do some regex substitutions on it, and write it back out in the same encoding.

However, the resulting file I get always seems to be UTF-8 (according to Notepad++ at least), mangling some characters.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
private static void editFile(File source, File target) {

    // Source and target encoding
    Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

    // Read the file as a single string
    String fileContent = null;

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source, iso88591charset)) {
    
        fileContent = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
                
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not read input file as a single String.", exception);
        return;
    }

    // Do some regex substitutions on the fileContent string
    String newContent = regex(fileContent);

    // Write the file back out in target encoding
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(target), iso88591charset))) {
    
        writer.write(newContent);
        
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not write out edited file!", exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any evident error, but I have two suggestions: use [StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#ISO_8859_1) directly and maybe you don't need a `BufferedWriter` and you can use the same `write(String)` method from the `OutputStreamWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing actually wrong with your code. Notepad++ sees the file encoded in UTF-8 because on a basic level there is no difference between UTF-8 and the encoding you're trying to use. Only specific characters differ and some (a lot) are missing from ISO compared to UTF. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or by simply searching `ISO-8859-1 vs UTF-8` in Google.

[I've created a simple project with your code](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/tree/63363359) and tested it with characters that are different for the ISO encoding - the result is a file that IntelliJ (and probably Notepad++ as well - cannot easily check, I'm on Linux) recognizes as ISO-8859-1. Apart from that, I've added another class that makes use of new (JDK11) features from `Files` class. The `new Scanner(source, charset)` that you've used was added in JDK10, so I think that you may be using 11 already. Here's the simplified code:

```
private static void editFile(File source, File target) {
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
    String fileContent;
    try {
        fileContent = Files.readString(source.toPath(), charset);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("Could not read input file as a single String.");
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    String newContent = regex(fileContent);
    try {
        Files.writeString(target.toPath(), newContent, charset);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.err.println("Could not write out edited file!");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Feel free to clone the repository or check it on GitHub and use whichever code version you prefer.